# Application bar | Windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone, application-bar

Is it possible to show application bar in windows phone 7 or higher at the top of application rather than at the bottom and also customizing the application bar. i-e.

Icon1 Icon2 Some text Icon3 Icon4.

Answer (score 2):

No. The application bar supports very little customization.
The only things you cna customize are the number of buttons (up to 4) and the color of the bar.
It is not possible to customize the position of the bar or combine icons and text.